# Create new column based on values in LIST in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question seems so simple yet I'm having so much trouble, and haven't seen it asked anywhere. I have a column that contains a different list in each row, and all I want to do is create a new column based on if a specific value is in that list. Data looks like this:

```
Col1
[5,6,23,7,20,21]    
[0,7,20,21]
[3,4,5,23,7,20,21]
[2,3,23,7,20,21]
[3,4,5,23,7,20,21]
```

Each number corresponds to a specific value, so `0 = 'apple'`, `2 = 'grape'`, etc...

While there are multiple values in each list, I'm really only looking for certain values, specifically `0, 2, 4, 6, 16, 17`

So what I want to do is add a new column, with the value that corresponds to the number that's found within `Col1`.

This is what the solution should be:

```
Col1               Col2
[5,6,23,7,20,21]   Pear
[0,7,20,21]        Apple
[3,4,5,23,7,20,21] Watermelon
[2,3,23,7,20,21]   Grape
[16,20,21]         Pineapple
```

I have tried:

```
df['Col2'] = np.where(0 in df['Col1'], 'Apple',
                np.where(2 in df['Col1'], 'Grape', 
                   np.where(4 in df['Col1'], 'Watermelon', )
```

And so on... But this defaults all values to `Apple`

```
Col1               Col2
[5,6,23,7,20,21]   Apple
[0,7,20,21]        Apple
[3,4,5,23,7,20,21] Apple
[2,3,23,7,20,21]   Apple
[16,20,21]         Apple
```

I was able to successfully do it by putting the above in a `for` loop, but I am getting issues. Code:

```
df['Col2'] = ''
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
   df['Col2'][i] = np.where(0 in df['Col1'][i], 'Apple',
                   np.where(2 in df['Col1'][i], 'Grape', 
                      np.where(4 in df['Col1'][i], 'Watermelon', )
```

I get the result I am looking for, but I am being met with a warning:

```
<ipython-input-638-5dfd74b69688>:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I assume the warning is because I have already created the blank column, but the only reason I did this is because I would get an error if I didn't create it. Furthermore, when I attempt to perform a simple `df['Col2'].value_counts()`, I get an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`. The result from `value_counts()` still shows up even though I get this error, which is odd.

I am not entirely sure how else to proceed, I've tried a bunch of other things to create this column but none have been able to work. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Where do you get your fruit names based on the first item in `col1`? Is it another list or you've just defined them constantly? If they are defined by yourself and not too large, you can write with `switch case`, otherwise write that data table too.

Comment: It is just a small list of just 6 different fruit names. In total there are maybe ~40 but I only need to use 0,2,4,6,16,17

Comment: @coderX. Is it possible to have two fruits in the same list?

Comment: It is possible, but extremely rare. Out of ~250 rows there was 1 where there were 2 fruits in the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explode`:

```
d = {0: 'Apple', 2: 'Grape', 4: 'Watermelon', 6: 'Banana', 16: 'Pear', 17: 'Orange'}
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].explode().map(d).dropna().groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)
print(df)

# Output:
                       Col1        Col2
0     [5, 6, 23, 7, 20, 21]      Banana
1            [0, 7, 20, 21]       Apple
2  [3, 4, 5, 23, 7, 20, 21]  Watermelon
3     [2, 3, 23, 7, 20, 21]       Grape
4  [3, 4, 5, 23, 7, 20, 21]  Watermelon
```

Comment: This is nice, because if there are multiple matches in one list, it will join them by `, ` e.g. `Apples, Oranges` in one row.

Comment: @coderX. If you have multiple fruits in the same list, they will be join like 'Apple, Banana, Grape, ...'

Comment: Of course, thanks @Corralien ! Saved me an hour of pulling my hair out trying different variations of `in` and `.isin`

Comment: Just a tip. When you have a list, think `explode` to have scalar values instead a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the list values and map them to the correct fruit,  ignoring the unwanted ones. Set to NaN if there is no match. Use `str.join` to include the possibility of multiple matches.

To apply this logic row-wise use `Series.apply`

```
import numpy as np

mapping = {0: 'Apple', 2: 'Grape', 4: 'Watermelon'}

df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda lst: ', '.join(mapping[n] for n in lst if n in mapping) or np.nan)
```

Output:

```
>>> df

                       Col1        Col2
0     [5, 6, 23, 7, 20, 21]         NaN
1            [0, 7, 20, 21]       Apple
2  [3, 4, 5, 23, 7, 20, 21]  Watermelon
3     [2, 3, 23, 7, 20, 21]       Grape
4  [3, 4, 5, 23, 7, 20, 21]  Watermelon
```

---

**Performance**

Note that this is should be faster than Corralien's solution.

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': [[5, 6, 23, 7, 20, 21],
             [0, 7, 20, 21],
             [3, 4, 5, 23, 7, 20, 21],
             [2, 3, 23, 7, 20, 21],
             [3, 4, 5, 23, 7, 20, 21]]
})

mapping = {0: 'Apple', 2: 'Grape', 4: 'Watermelon'}

def number_to_fruit(lst):
    return ', '.join(mapping[n] for n in lst if n in mapping) or np.nan

# Simulate a large DataFrame
n = 20000
df = pd.concat([df]*n, ignore_index=False)

>>> df.shape

(100000, 1)
```

Timmings:

```
# Using apply. (I've added dropna for a more fair comparison)
>>> %timeit -n 10 df['Col1'].apply(number_to_fruit).dropna()

116 ms ± 7.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Corralien's solution 
>>> %timeit -n 10 df['Col1'].explode().map(mapping).dropna().groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)

710 ms ± 71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @coderX I updated my answer with a simple performance test. Have a look.